# Using Regex to hide all URL's except known SAFE URL's

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a Regex that effectively scrubs/masks all URL's from a string of text except those from a domain that I know/trust.

For example, the domains I trust are safedomain.com and safedomain.com.au, and may be presented in the string as any of the following 'SAFE' combinations (with or without text in front or after)

I've been able to write a regex that identifies any of these SAFE URL's in any format (i.e. with/without HTTP, WWW, .com and .com.au)

```
((?:(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/)?(?:www\.|\b)(?:safedomain\.(?:com\.au|com)(?:[\\\/]\S*|\w*)))
```

I've also found an example of a regex that can successfully identify ALL URL's within a given string

```
((?:(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/)?(?:[\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))(?:[\w.,@?^=%&:\\\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?)
```

So from here, I thought I could simply next each regex above it's own capture group, and use a Negative Lookahead to compared the two. If the result from the SAFE regex matches the ALL regex, then ignore the result. Otherwise if there's no match, then the ALL URL is substituted with a #hidden# value

So this was my attempt (also here https://regex101.com/r/RJp1PD/2)

```
(?!(?:(?:(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/)?(?:www\.|\b)(?:safedomain\.(?:com\.au|com)(?:[\\\/]\S*|\w*))))(?:(?:(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/)?(?:[\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))(?:[\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\\\/~+#-])?)
```

It's working at hiding the non-matching ALL URL's - however it's still trying to replace SAFE URL after the first character, e.g. **safedomain.com** is changed to **s#hidden#**

It's my fist time trying to use a negative lookahead, so any pointers on where I've gone wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the negative lookahead is doing is checking for each position if a SAFE URL follows, and if it does, it will skip this position **without consuming any characters**, which means it will just step to next character. There the negative lookahead will not find a SAFE URL, so the rest of the statement will be checked and it will find a valid URL, e.g. "afedomain.com", which it will match and therefore replace.

What you can do to fix this is to only check the complete URL, which means the position to be checked has to be the start of an URL, i.e. it's at the start of the line or follows a space. You can do this with a negative lookbehind for a word character or a dot: `(?<!\.|\w)`

```
(?<!\.|\w)(?!(?:(?:(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/)?(?:www\.|\b)(?:safedomain\.(?:com\.au|com)(?:[\\\/]\S*|\w*))))(?:(?:(?:http|ftp|https):\/\/)?(?:[\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))(?:[\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\\\/~+#-])?)
```

As a side note: Your regex would not match something like safedomain.com.fake.com

Comment: You are an AWESOME human being! Thank you so much, that is working great. I still have a lot to learn so I appreciate the explanation as well.